# error : gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, deployment, unicorn

When I tryed deploying my rails application, the log said error below.

```
EBUG [4b7b573d]     An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as [----]: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as [------]: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

my gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

How can I solved this and Why is it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to config/deploy.rb, the settings line:

```
set :bundle_without, [:development, :test]
```